# Get-Content | Select-String return top only row from resultset

Tags: powershell

Fetching top row only from below command:

```
$G = Get-Content $SourceFile | select-string -pattern $SearchKeyword2`**
```

Above command return multiple line numbers it has found in document, we want to select the top 1 .. returned. How can we apply filter to this to return only one top row.. like we can do in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -First 1`:

```
$G = Get-Content $SourceFile | Select-String -Pattern $SearchKeyword2 | Select-Object -First 1
```